# Creating a transparent background but keeping text and icon non-transparent

Tags: android, android-layout

```
AndroidStudio 1.5
```

Hello,

I am trying to create a transparent background that the icons and text are on. But I don't want to icons or the text to be transparent. In the `dialer_pad.xml` I have tried setting the alpha but each time I do this the icons and text will also become transparent.

As you can see the icons and text are transparent. I just want the background to be transparent.

[image]

I have tried many things to set the alpha to just get the surrounding background to be transparent while leaving the text and icons alone. I thought making a layer-list might work.

Is this possible?

Many thanks on any suggestions,

contacts.xml

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/inner_border">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivContacts"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_people_white_48dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvHold"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Contacts"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

call.xml

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/right_border">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivSwitch"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_phone_white_48dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvHold"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Make Call"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

dialer_pad.xml

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/outer_border"
    android:alpha="0.5">

    <TableRow>
        <include
            layout="@layout/call"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <include
            layout="@layout/contacts"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.ssd.MainActivity"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/background">

    <include layout="@layout/dialer_pad"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: getBackground().setAlpha() doesnt help you?

Comment: FrameLayout container with alpha 0-1
Text, icons  inside

Comment: @pvllnspk Having the alpha set on the FrameLayout will add the transparency to the children so that the image and text will be transparent. I just want the background that the text and icons are on to be transparent. Leaving the icons and text without any transparency.

Comment: use 2 FrameLayout: the second above the first(1 - with alpha you need, 2 - fully transparent that contains childs) - so these layouts will be on the same hierarchy level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have in your `outer_border.xml` a `color` with a `transparency` instead:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/outer_border" >

...
</TableLayout>
```

If you want `transparent blue` you could have it like: `#550000FF`

Comment: @Iuiscosta, that actually works quite well. This is the best answer so far.

Answer (score 0):

in "dialer_pad.xml" with that way, alpha is effective with all of they child, inclue .
So you need to remove alpha at TableLayout of dialer_pad.xml.

and edit your child layout like that.

contacts.xml

```
 <FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
       >
       <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivContacts"
            android:layout_height="match_parrent"
            android:layout_width="match_parrent"
            android:alpha="0.5"
            android:background="@drawable/inner_border"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivContacts"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_people_white_48dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvHold"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Contacts"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"/>
    </FrameLayout>
```

same with call.xml

Comment: @ZaiNguyen, I tried you suggestion, but unless I have something wrong. There was no transparency on anything. I just want the background that the text and icons are on to be transparent. No transparency for the icons or text. Hope I am clear. Thanks.